# How do I prevent the "Remove risky access to your data" warning?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I wrote a few Apps Script just for myself with no intention of publishing them or having anyone else use them. Yet in the Google Security Check-up it lists the scripts and states "Remove risky access to your data".

Under each script it says things like:

- Has access to Gmail, Google Docs, Google Drive, YouTube
- Has access to Google Docs, Google Drive
  etc.

And there's a blue button that says "Remove Access". But if I press that button I won't be able to use my scripts.

How do retain use of my scripts but assuage Google's fear (and my own) that the scripts are some kind of security issue?

Answer (score 3):

The only way to remove that would be to have your application verified by google.

As this is a single user app and you are the only one using it there is no need to go though the verification process.

There really is no way to remove the warning from Google Security Check-up.

Note: I sent off an email to google oauth2 team to see if there isnt something they can do about it.  I have serval such scripts and agree its annoying.

Comment: Ok good to know...wasn't sure if I was missing something simple to suppress the messages. I agree there should be a way to allow single user apps to avoid these hoops.